# Is behavior clearly defined in c for doing a bitwise OR operator between different size variables and subtracting a larger uint from a smaller uint?

Tags: c, logical-operators, assignment-operator

I'm trying to figure out what the end result of the following commands in c would be, and what might be a better way to go about it.

Here are my variables. All are unsigned integers of type either `uint16` or `uint32`

`CNT_A`: This is a `uint32`* but represents a 16-bit read/write counter register in the microprocessor. It points directly to the address of this register, so this always contains the value from the register. It is automatically incremented by the processor, but can be reset or written to a set value by the program. From the manufacturer's documentation, the upper 16-bits are "reserved" and therefore, I believe, always report `0` and won't actually be written, so it is actually a 16-bit value.

```
*NOTE: `CNT_A` is always called as a `uint32` in the code, but it is declared as a union of a `uint32` and a 32-bit `bitfield`, with the upper 16 bits of the bitfield unused.
```

`update_counter`: this is a 'volatile uint16' which is incremented in another function whenever that function is called.

`detect_pulse` is `boolean` which is TRUE if a pulse is detected in the system

`ignore_time` is a const uint16

`wTempA`: this is a `uint16` that pulls the 16-bit counter value from `REG_A`

`lwTempB`: this is a `uint32` (`l`=`long`) that is used as a temporary variable that stores two 16-bit values, but is involved in 32-bit calculations

`lwTempC`: this is a `uint32` that is used to detect a change via differences in the other variables

'lwLastA': this is a static `uint32` that stores the final value of `lwTempA` and carries it to the next call of the function and is compared to the new `lwTempA`

Here are the relevant actual pieces of code in the function (note comments shown are ones I added for this post, not in actual file):

```
void changeHandler(void) {

    wTempA = REG_A;             //Assigning a uint32 to a uint16, but upper 16 bits of uint32 are always 0
    lwTempB = update_counter;   //Assigning a uint16 to a uint32
    lwTempB <<= 16;             //Shifting uint16 value to upper 16 bits
    lwTempB |= wTempA           //Doing a logical OR of a uint16 with a uint32, then storing back to that uint32
    ...
    if (detect_pulse)
    {
        lwLastA = wTempA            //Setting "previous" value to wTempA if a pulse was detected
    }

    lwtempC = lwTempB - lwLastA     //Subtracting uint16 from a uint32

    if (lwTempC <= ignore_time) //There must be a significant difference to perform the following actions
    {
          return;
    }

    //...perform important actions with micro... (redacted)

    ...

    lwLastA = wTempA            //Setting previous value of wTempA

}
```

I inherited this function from a previous programmer. It is not the way I would do it, but I don't want to rewrite the entire thing if I don't have to.

The function, I believe, should trigger the "important actions" if one of two conditions occur. One is if an outside event occurs that causes `update_counter` to increment, the other is if more time has passed than `ignore_time`.

Is all of the expected behavior for each of these lines above clearly defined and will it produce consistent results?

A few specific concerns I have:

1. Is it clearly defined that the bitwise OR between lwTempB (uint32) and wTempA (uint16) will compare the lower 16-bits.
2. `update_counter` will roll-over after a certain amount of time passes (the events it counts occur at a set frequency unless there's a problem), at that roll-over point, lwLastA will actually be larger than lwTempB. Will there be clearly defined behavior here, where a two unsigned integers are subtracted in a way that would normally yield a negative result, and then it is being assigned to an unsigned integer? From the boolean math, I think this will result in lwTempC always having a value larger than ignore_time and therefore cause a trigger still, so the sloppy coding should still provide the desired result?

Comment: You're asking about [integer promotions](https://en.cppreference.com/w/c/language/conversion).

Comment: "Reserved" for reads usually means "values are unpredictable and should be ignored", not "reads as zero". That way, they can gain meaning in a future version and not break existing code.

Comment: One important question: what size is `int` on this platform?  In several of C's promotion rules, it makes a difference whether a given type is larger or smaller than `int`.  Even if you try to write all your code with explicitly sized types like `uint16, uint32`, the details of the basic types `int`, `long int`, etc, are still there in the background.  There are a few cases where this actually affects the behavior, and in any case it is important in explaining how the rules lead to the behavior that occurs.

Comment: Is that comparison `lwTempC <= ignore_time` the right way round?

Comment: @NateEldredge good point. The project this is in is using a 32-bit processor using the ILP32 data model. uint16 and uint32 are defined in a header file as follows: `typedef unsigned long  uint32 ;
typedef unsigned short  uint16 ;
typedef unsigned char  uint8 ;`

Comment: @IanAbbott good catch. The comparison WAS the right way around, but the code following it was incorrect. If the comparison was true, it's supposed to exit the function and wait for the next call. If false, it continues with the rest of the function. I corrected it now.

Comment: It looks like you're trying to simulate a 32 bit counter but the actual H/W is only 16 bits. `update_counter` is the upper 16 bits of this 32 bit counter. So, near the top, wouldn't you need: `if (wTempA < lwLastA) ++update_counter;` to increment if the upper bits if the lower bits rollover?

Comment: @CraigEstey yes, it is but there's more to it. The HW reports 16-bit numbers padded to 32-bit. Also, `wTempA` is not just a copy of the counter. It only gets updated when certain events occur. An interrupt function is called when the HW overflow flag is set that increments update_counter (a global variable) - but still doesn't update the entire 32-bit value until the event is detected. lwLastA is the time the last event occurred and lwTempA is the time of the current event that triggers this function. There's also conditions where events are ignored.

Answer (score -1):

There is *implementation defined behaviour*. That means, the C language doesn't define the behaviour, but your implementation (compiler and standard library) must.

In an integer operation, both sides are promoted to the int, unsigned int, long or unsigned long, depending on rules given by your compiler. Now one of the types involved is "unsigned short". On a 16 bit system, short and int could both be 16 bits, so unsigned short cannot be "promoted" to int, but to unsigned int instead. On a 32 bit system, int would be 32 bit, and unsigned short would be promoted to int. So your operation could be performed with unsigned int or with int operands, and that makes a difference. Especially if you compare numbers.

Turn on all available warnings, and hopefully you will be told about unwanted behaviour.

Comment: Re “In an integer operation, both sides are promoted to the int, unsigned int, long or unsigned long, depending on rules given by your compiler”: (a) This is unduly simplified, so much so that it may lead to wrong conclusions and bugs in code. (b) The rules are set by the C standard, although they depend on some type properties defined by the implementation. (c) Most binary arithmetic operators use the *usual arithmetic conversions*, not the *integer promotions*. The integer promotions do not change values; the conversions might…

Comment: … (d) The operands may be converted to even wider types than `unsigned long` if one of the operands is wider. (e) The widths of types are decided by the C implementation, not by whether the target is “16 bit” or “32 bit”. There is no single property that defines a “16 bit” or “32 bit” system; systems have multiple features that have various widths: bus width, processor register width, instruction operands, and more. C implementations are usually influenced by target properties but may chose their integer widths for other reasons.